# How can I parse XML using ruby for a duplicate tag?

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, jruby, assert

```
   <recipes>
  <recipe name="MPEG4w480f20h360AAC" mimeType="video/mp4" width="480" height="360" />
  <recipe name="MP3" mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
  <recipe name="j24" mimeType="image/jpeg" width="24" height="24" />
  <recipe name="j64" mimeType="image/jpeg" width="64" height="64" />
  <recipe name="j128" mimeType="image/jpeg" width="128" height="128" />
  <recipe name="j88" mimeType="image/jpeg" height="88" />
  <recipe name="j150" mimeType="image/jpeg" height="150" />
  <recipe name="hqPivot" mimeType="image/jpeg" width="600" />
   </recipes>
```

I am writing Ruby script to verify that the XML Structure.

```
assert(!XPath.match(xml, "recipes/recipe[@name]").empty?, "Structure of xml incorrect")
```

How can I verify all  one by one?

Comment: I didn't get your question ?

Comment: how can I verify all [@names] present under <recipe>?

Comment: `//recipes/recipe[@name]` will give all `recipe` which has @name present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = File.open("test.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)

tags = []

doc.xpath("//recipe/@name").each do |elem| # get all name of all recipes
  tags << elem.value
end

p tags # show all tags
p tags == tags.uniq # are all tags unique?

f.close
```

This output (using your sample):

```
["MPEG4w480f20h360AAC", "MP3", "j24", "j64", "j128", "j88", "j150", "hqPivot"]
true
```